# Unknown pseudo-element or pseudo-class :focus-within

Tags: css, w3c-validation

i am getting this error in w3 validations is there any way to solve it i tried many ways but not able to resolve it.[image]

Comment: W3C only has this in Draft specification, so maybe that the reason why it pops the problem 
https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-focus-within-pseudo
Though a few browsers supported the pseudo (https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within)
To be valid against something not yet released. I'm not sure we can do that

Comment: is  there any way to escape this error?

Comment: simply ignore it, if it works fine then it's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `focus-within` is in a draft to be release with css [selector4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/)

If you check support for it [caniuse:focus-within](https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within) you can see that 3 of the main browser support it on their latest versions.

W3c Validator will check against the latest Release ATM selectors 3, if you go specifically to [W3C CSS Validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_uri+with_options) you can see under more options that it will only allow you to select up to version 3.

So that is the reason of the error, as by their check its actually an error.

What to do from here: it all depends

Comment: `more options that it will only allow you to select up to version 3` --> this option isn't related to the level of the feature but to CSS, it will always be CSS3 even if we have some features at Level 4 https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#css-levels --> `There is no CSS Level 4. Independent modules can reach level 4 or beyond, but CSS the language no longer has levels.`